# Radio Button Grid

Tags: python, user-interface, grid, radio-button

Backstory: I'm new at writing GUIs and I'm attempting to make a grid of radio buttons.  I have this so far but for some reason when I pass in the arguments it hits the line "self.radio_button_list[0] = setChecked.(True)" and then throws a list index out of range error.  Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it? Is there a better way to make a grid of radio buttons (or a dropdown menu, there are 51 options)?

I initialize with the line:

```
self.radio_button_widget = RadioButtonWidget('File Types', "Please select the type of file to edit", ('adhdrs_on_bd', 'adhdrs_on_bm', 'alabama', 'asr', 'atq', 'bsa', 'caars_on_bd'))
```

which then calls:

```
from PyQt4 import *  
class RadioButtonWidget(QtGui.QWidget):  
    def __init__(self, label, instruction, button_list):  
        super(RadioButtonWidget,self).__init__()  
        self.titleLabel = QtGui.QLabel(label)  
        self.radio_group_box= QtGui.QGroupBox(instruction)  
        self.radio_button_group = QtGui.QButtonGroup()  

        self.radio_button_list = []  
        for each in self.radio_button_list:  
            self.radio_button_list.append(QtGui.QRadioButton(each))


        self.radio_button_list[0].setChecked(True) 

        self.radio_button_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        counter = 1
        for each in self.radio_button_list:
            self.radio_button_layout.addWidget(each)
            self.radio_button_group.addButton(each)
            self.radio_button_group.setID(each, counter)
            counter += 1
        self.radio_group_box.setLayout(self.radio_button_layout)


        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.titleLabel)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.radio_group_box)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)




    def selected_button(self):
        return self.radio_button_group.checkedId()
```

Comment: I'd guess that your `radio_button_list` is empty. You're creating it empty, then iterate through its 0 elements, and append each element to the list... and then you attempt to index it. You probably meant to iterate through `button_list`?

Comment: I added in the line that initializes the widget.  It should add in the file names and then iterate through the list, correct?

Comment: Changing `for each in self.radio_button_list` to `for each in button_list` should fix it.

Comment: >that feel when I'm being an idiot.  Yeah.  That worked.  Thanks!